# Can you tell if a page does exist even if it throws a 404?

Tags: linux, apache

Is it possible to determine that a page actually exists when it is designed to throw a `404 NOT FOUND`?

On my server, when a request to a script is made while passing invalid parameters, I am throwing a 404 http status code because I don't want those with no knowledge of the system to know the page (public URL) exists. I am hoping that throwing a 404 will make an attacker think the script does not exist.  No resources on the server itself actually direct to the script, it would all be from external requests.

What I really want to know is, from just the response, would someone be able to tell the difference between a page that does not exist and a page configured to return a 404?

The response headers when making an invalid request to the script do indicate a **http status** of 404, and **not** a http status of 200 with a 404 page displayed.

Below is the response header I am getting when I make an invalid request.

```
HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
Date: Fri, 27 Jan 2017 23:32:28 GMT
Server: Apache
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.4.16
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
Content-Length: 0
Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=100
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
```

**EDIT:**
Below is the response header I am getting when I hit a page that truly does not exist.

```
HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
Date: Tue, 31 Jan 2017 19:08:06 GMT
Server: Apache
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
Content-Length: 203
Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=99
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
```

Comment: @schroeder Yes, I do want a page that exists to throw a 404.  I'm not assuming that an attacker wouldn't get knowledge of my system, but if they don't have that knowledge, would they be able to determine if the page existed from just the response?

Comment: Ok, so is your real question, "is there a way to determine that a page does in fact exist if it throws a 404?"

Comment: @elsadek An attacker likely would know the service existed, but not know the URL used for this service.  No internal pages indicate the URL for this service.

Comment: @Mocking I think, at this point, you might need to overhaul your question text. It's a little disjointed and difficult to follow. I'll take a stab at it, and you can revert if I miss the mark.

Comment: I'm unsure, because it could depend on the actual Apache configuration, but that field `X-Powered-By: PHP/5.4.16` might be a hint. Does it exist for truely missing pages? Maybe you could add a response got for a truely missing page in your question.

Comment: Why don't you design your page so it's secure even if an attacker does know it exists? Then you don't need to pretend it doesn't exist.

Comment: Have you compared your "fake" 404 to a page that really doesn't exist?

Comment: @immibis check my updated answer

Comment: @schroeder It's perfect.  Thank you for the help, I appreciate it.

Comment: @SergeBallesta looks like you were right, it is missing for pages that don't exist.  I'm gonna upvote your answer now but you should put that in your answer cause it was right.

Comment: @immibis looks like you were also right.  Thanks for the help guys.

Comment: I'll accept whatever answer is edited to include all of them so it's fair.  Thank you for the help everyone.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Throwing 404 error for every invalid request could be questionable, an attacker may start suspecting this behavior specially if he knows the service he is targeting.
 
Does this help protecting your service ? this really depends on the perseverance of the attacker.

**Edit**:
**The attacker can detect the difference if you don't craft the 404 response header properly as the server would do**
Here is a PoC for Java server case (Tomcat8):
This is a 'truthful' 404 status returned by the server itself for any not found resource :

```
Content-Language:en
Content-Length:1026
Content-Type:text/html;charset=utf-8
Date:Tue, 31 Jan 2017 09:15:54 GMT
Server:Apache-Coyote/1.1
```

This one is returned by the servlet :

```
Content-Language:en
Content-Length:992
Content-Type:text/html;charset=utf-8
Date:Tue, 31 Jan 2017 09:18:04 GMT
Server:Apache-Coyote/1.1
```

You notice the parameter's value of **"Content-length"** in both cases, this one could attract the attacker's attention.

Comment: Content length was also right.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: You mean the param 's values was different ? I think you got the answer

Answer (score 2):

Beware, hiding actual error code smells a little as obfuscation. There is nothing really bad from a security point of view, but it adds little security if any. Do you really think that attackers blindly accept error codes? You know they can be changed at will, and they do too. Ok, it can be useful against script kiddies but not facing a serious attack, so you should really think about what is your threat model before going that way.

And there could be a drawback here. Unless you build a special log system that logs the internal error, you will end in logs containing only 404 errors. That means that **you** have lost any possibility of log analysis to try to discover attacks to your site and possible security flaws. IMHO error code are more useful for the maintainer of an application that for an attacker...

Comment: I think the question is: how *would* attackers be able to pierce this obfuscation?

Comment: note that I just overhauled the question while you composed your answer - sorry for confusion

Answer (score 1):

The same idea applies with user authentication.

Most web services as you have seen, will not tell you what is wrong in your  username and password. It will give you a general prompt saying that something with the whole pair was invalid. This leaves the attacker not knowing if the username is incorrect, the password was incorrect, or the pair itself was incorrect.

It's much faster to determine *if the user exists* **compared to** *does the user exist, and is the password correct*. Some attackers will take this into account when trying to gain access to a system by timings.

Likewise the same holds for a 404 (Not Found) vs. 403 (Not authorized). It's faster for the webserver to return a 404 than a 403, but the timings here could be so small, the margin of error might take over.

It's not unheard of to always spit out a 404 instead of both 404/403. A web server such as Apache can customize it's response to a web page request. It's a little harder to change the HTTP return code, but it is certainly easier to modify the page the user sees. Just as with the username/password idea, the attacker is left with two cases:

- Does this resource actually exist?
- Do I have to be authorized before I have access to this?

It's more common now for server sided code to handle authorization and authentication without having the web server return a 404/403 code. Server sided code will normally handle such requests, and the web server will simply return a 200 or 300 code. The contents of the page may say 403, but the HTTP code will be 200 or 300. 403 is used for HTTP authentication which has lost popularity over time.

Comment: I do want to point out however, that my whole purpose of doing this was so that attackers wouldn't even know the script existed to begin with.

Comment: @Mocking Since the web server will always return a 200 or 300 code with server sided code (unless it's overburdened or something), all that requires changing is the page displayed to users. You can simply make it generic by "Invalid access". Does the resource exist? Do I have to sign in? What accounts have access to the resource? These are potential questions an attacker will have to answer with a generic page.

Comment: By 200 or 300 code, do you mean http status code?  With an invalid request my page returns a 404 status code.

Comment: @Mocking There is a hierarchy to the web server. The server it self will first determine if the page exists. If it doesn't, the server will return a 404 code. If the page does exist, the web server will let the server sided code (PHP/ASP/Etc.) run, and then return a 200 or 300 HTTP code along with the contents from the PHP/ASP script.

Comment: The php script itself is throwing a 404 http response code though, and when I check the headers when I try to hit the script with an invalid request, it shows a http status code of 404.

Comment: @Mocking if the script is returning a 404, then it will need either removal or modification. At least in PHP 7 the code for a HTTP header code would be http_response_code(404);

Comment: That is the exact code am I using, however I am not sure what you mean by "200 or 300 http code".  Are you saying there is a way to discern that the script does in fact exist?  I think you're trying to say I'm just loading a generic 404 page with a http status of 200, not actually returning a 404 error, but the http header does show a http status of 404.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#2xx_Success

Comment: I did read that before asking this question, and you commenting that leads me to believe this is not the answer I am looking for.

Comment: "It's a little harder to change the HTTP return code" this is absolutely wrong,  any web dev language has the ability to craft http headers including the return code.